# Javascript sort array by age group followed by gender

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array according to age group, followed by gender. I have came up with a solution, and it works, but I think that the code could be improved somewhere along the line but I could not figure out how. Here is the sample input:

```
// removed
```

My code:

```
// removed code
```

The output I am getting which is correct:

```
male 2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
female 0,0,0,1,3,1,0,0,0
```

I am pretty sure there are better ways in terms of speed performance to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: `Math.floor(age / 10)`

Comment: Also, not obvious why you use `maleData.splice` instead of directly assigning to `maleData` array via index, like `maleData[ageIndex] = 1`. You also don't need to check if `femaleData[ageIndex] == 0`, that check is really redundant.

Comment: @zerkms I see I see but in term of performance speed, is there any better way to achieve the desired result above? Because I realized that the sorting alreayd runs quite slow for a small set of data

Comment: "I realized that the sorting alreayd runs quite slow for a small set of data" --- provide more details: amount of data, how you measure it.

Comment: @zerkms I don't know, I plotted multuple graphs at the same time and this chart comes out the slowest. I guess it is something to do with the sorting. As for the data, I have 30 accounts, 30 receipts and many other receipt items which contributed to this set of data. I am pretty sure there are better way to do this, am I right?

Comment: Yep, I have already explained how to do it the better way. PS: sorting 30 elements cannot be slow. Even 30 thousand elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code takes between 4 and 6 ms to execute on your sample data.

```
function ageIndex(elem) {
    var age = elem[0].age;
    if (age <= 0) return 0;
    else if (age > 80) return 8;
    else return Math.floor((age - 1) / 10);
}

function gender(elem) { return elem[0].gender }

var ageGroup = ['0-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61-70', '71-80', '80+'];

var maleData = new Array(ageGroup.length).fill(0);

var femaleData = new Array(ageGroup.length).fill(0);

l = arr.length;

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (gender(arr[i]) == "male") maleData[ageIndex(arr[i])]++;
    else femaleData[ageIndex(arr[i])]++;
}

console.log("male " + maleData)
console.log("female " + femaleData)
```

This one consistently gives me 1 ms. Maybe it's because I stored the array length in a variable, rather than calculating it every time.

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to consider changing the name of the "80+" group to "81+".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var obj = [[{"age":41,"gender":"male"}],[{"age":10,"gender":"male"}],[{"age":10,"gender":"male"}],[{"age":31,"gender":"female"}],[{"age":58,"gender":"female"}],[{"age":50,"gender":"female"}],[{"age":50,"gender":"female"}],[{"age":50,"gender":"female"}]];

var result = obj.reduce(function(data,a){
  ++data[a[0]['gender']][a[0]['age'] > 80 ? data[a[0]['gender']].length : Math.ceil(a[0]['age'] / 10 - 1)];
  return data;
},{'male' : Array(9).fill(0), 'female' : Array(9).fill(0)});

console.log(result);
```

If you want to sort the object, you can use custom sort function

```js
var obj = [[{"age":41,"gender":"male"}],[{"age":10,"gender":"male"}],[{"age":10,"gender":"male"}],[{"age":31,"gender":"female"}],[{"age":58,"gender":"female"}],[{"age":50,"gender":"female"}],[{"age":50,"gender":"female"}],[{"age":50,"gender":"male"}],[{"age":50,"gender":"female"}]]

var result = obj.sort(function(a,b){
    return a[0].age - b[0].age || a[0].gender.localeCompare(b[0].gender);
});

console.log(result);
```